# Problems with cregg and cjoint

Tags: r, ggplot2, devtools

I am trying to load the packages and they come up with an error message that says `ggstance` (dependent package) doesn't exist. Heard that `ggstance` was under devtools but the package page says `ggstance` is now under `ggplot2`. I updated `ggplot2` and get the same error message that

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘cregg’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘ggstance’

Any work around ideas? I've deleted and reloaded R, updated packages, etc and nothing is working.

Comment: the `ggstance` package is [still on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggstance). Unless you have a *very* old version of R, `install.packages("ggstance")` should just work ... ??

Comment: I try to load it and "get One or more of the packages to be updated are currently loaded. Restarting R prior to install is highly recommended.

RStudio can restart R before installing the requested packages. All work and data will be preserved during restart.

Do you want to restart R prior to install?"  and this" ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggstance’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggstance’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggstance’ had non-zero exit status"

Comment: Did you in fact restart R?  You should do this from a *clean* R session - no packages loaded.